# Disable/Hide Elastic search default endpoint access from browser

Tags: elasticsearch

When I navigate to the ElasticSearch endpoint from the browser, it returns the cluster details like below. Is there any way to disable/hide these details

```
{
  "name" : "cybertron-node-1",
  "cluster_name" : "cybertron-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "rxF850LBSuuqBCT8wGQOXA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.1.1",
    "build_hash" : "bd92e7f",
    "build_date" : "2017-12-17T20:23:25.338Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.1.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: Where are you hosting your Elasticsearch instance, on what machine? Do you need public access to the instance?

Comment: @samy Elasticsearch instance hosted in a separate server, we have hosted some microservices in another server. No need public access to the instance

Comment: If you only access it with a range of limited ips you could just configure a firewall with ufw on the port that only grants access to those ips

Answer (score 1):

6.1 is [EOL](https://www.elastic.co/support/eol) and unsupported, please upgrade as a matter of urgency!

the only way to do this would be to use access control, or roll your own proxy, which is free in 6.8/7.1 and above https://www.elastic.co/blog/security-for-elasticsearch-is-now-free